# Tensorflow: Is it possible to modify the global step in checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to modify the `global_step` in checkpoints so that I can move the training from one machine to another.

Let's say I was doing training for several days on machine A. Now I bought a new machine B with better graphic card and more GPU memory and would like to move the training from machine A to machine B.

In order to restore the checkpoints in machine B, I have previously specified the `global_step` in `Saver.save` in machine A but with smaller `batch_size` and larger `sub_iterations`.

```
batch_size=10
sub_iterations=500
for (...)
    for i in range(sub_iterations):
        inputs, labels = next_batch(batch_size)
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={inputs: inputs, labels: labels})

saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session, checkpoints_path, global_step)
```

Now I copied all the files including the checkpoints from machine A to machine B. Because machine B has more GPU memory, I can modify the `batch_size` to a larger value but use fewer `sub_iterations`.

```
batch_size=100
sub_iterations=50 # = 500 / (100/10)
for (...)
    for i in range(sub_iterations):
        inputs, labels = next_batch(batch_size)
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={inputs: inputs, labels: labels})
```

However we cannot directly restore the copied checkpoints as `global_step` is different in machine B. For example, `tf.train.exponential_decay` will produce incorrect `learning_rate` as the number of `sub_iterations` is reduced in machine B.

```
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(..., global_step, sub_iterations, decay_rate, staircase=True)
```

Is it possible to modify the `global_step` in checkpoints? Or there is an alternative but more appropriate way to handle this situation?

### Edit 1

In addition to calculating the `learning_rate`, I also used the global_step to calculate and reduce the number of iterations.

```
while i < iterations:
    j = 0

    while j < sub_iterations:
        inputs, labels = next_batch(batch_size)
        feed_dict_train = {inputs: inputs, labels: labels}
        _, gstep = session.run([optimizer, global_step], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
        if (i == 0) and (j == 0):
            i, j = int(gstep/ sub_iterations), numpy.mod(gstep, sub_iterations)
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

And we will start the iterations from new `i` and `j`. Please feel free to comment on this as it might not be a good approach to restore the checkpoints and continue training from loaded checkpoints.

### Edit 2

In machine A, let's say `iterations` is 10,000, `sub_iterations` is 500 and `batch_size` is 10. So the total number of batches we are aiming to train is 10000x500x10 = 50,000,000. Assume we have trained for several days and `global_step` becomes `501`. So the total number of batches trained is 501x10 = 5010. The remaining number of batches not trained is from 5011 to 50,000,000. If we apply `i, j = int(gstep/ sub_iterations), numpy.mod(gstep, sub_iterations)`, the last trained value of `i` is 501/500=1 and `j` is 501%500=1.

Now you have copied all the files including the checkpoints to machine B. Since B has more GPU memory and we can train for more batches for one sub-iteration, we set `batch_size` to 100, and adjust `sub_iterations` to 50 but leave `iterations` as 10000. The total number of batches to train is still 50,000,000. So the problem comes, how can we start and train the batches from 5011 to 50,000,000 and do not train again for first 5010 samples?

In order to start and train the batches from 5011 in machine B, we should set `i` to 1 and `j` to 0 because the total batches it has trained will be (1*50+0)*100 = 5,000 which is close to 5,010 (as the `batch_size` is 100 in machine B as opposed to 10 in machine A, we cannot start exactly from 5,010 and we can either choose 5,000 or 5,100).

If we do not adjust the `global_step` (as suggested by @coder3101), and use back `i, j = int(gstep/ sub_iterations), numpy.mod(gstep, sub_iterations)` in machine B, `i` will become 501/50=10 and `j` will become 501%50=1. So we will start and train from batch 50,100 (=501*`batch_size`=501*100) which is incorrect (not close to 5010).

This formula `i, j = int(gstep/ sub_iterations), numpy.mod(gstep, sub_iterations)` is introduced because if we stop the training in machine A at one point, we can restore the checkpoints and continue the training in machine A using this formula. However it seems this formula is not applicable when we move the training from machine A to machine B. Therefore I was hoping to modify the `global_step` in checkpoints to deal with this situation, and would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Your edit includes a code likely to throw ZeroDivisionError @ int (gstep/iterations) . You see iterations is zero when you execute this.
Also, I could not get what you wanted to convey by your EDIT. Please explain briefly.

Comment: @coder3101 I am sorry I have made a typo which I meant to divide/mod `sub_iterations`. Please kindly see my updated code which explains I have used the `gstep` restored from the checkpoints and set the `i` and `j` which effectively start from previous iteration last trained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

To modify the `global_step` in machine B, you have to perform the following steps:

### Calculate the corresponding `global_step`

In the above example, `global_step` in machine A is 501 and the total number of trained batches is 501x10=5010. So the corresponding `global_step` in machine B is 5010/100=50.

### Modify the checkpoint filenames

Modify the suffix of `model_checkpoint_path` and `all_model_checkpoint_paths` values to use correct step number (e.g. 50 in the above example) in /checkpoint.

Modify the filename of index, meta and data for the checkpoints to use correct step number.

### Override `global_step` after restoring checkpoint

```
saver.restore(session, model_checkpoint_path)
initial_global_step = global_step.assign(50)
session.run(initial_global_step)
...
# do the training
```

Now if you restore the checkpoints (including `global_step`) and override `global_step`, the training will use the updated `global_step` and adjust `i` and `j` and `learning_rate` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep decayed learning rate same on Machine B as it was on A, you can tweak other parameters of the function `tf.train.exponential_dacay` . For Example, you can change decay rate on the new machine.

In order to find that `decay_rate` you need to know how `exponential_decay` is computed.

> decay_learning_rate = learning_rate * decay_rate ^
>   (global_step/decay_steps)

`global_step/decay_step` yields an pure integer if staircase==True

Where `decay_steps` is your `sub_iteration` and `global_step` is from Machine A.

You can change the `decay_rate` in such a way that new learning rate on machine B is same or close to what you would expect from machine A at that `global_step`.

Also, you can change the initial learning rate for machine B so as to achieve uniform exponential rate decay from machine A to B.

So in short while importing from A to B you have changed 1 variable (`sub_iteration`), and kept `global_step` same. You can adjust the other 2 variables of `exponential_decay(..)`in such a way that your output learning rate from the function is same as you would expect from Machine A at that `global_step`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also use the global_step `gstep` returned from `_, gstep = session.run([optimizer, global_step], feed_dict=feed_dict_train)` to reduce the number of iterations. For example, if last saved step size is 1000 and I will reduce the loop to start from 1001 to total_iterations. How can I do this?

Comment: Re: `I could not get why you would do that`. I thought the whole point of restoring a checkpoint is to not train everything from start, and continue training from last step you have trained? In that case if you have 500,000 iterations and you have previously trained say 250,000, you would like to train from 250,001 to 500,000. Isn't it?

Comment: So what is the problem??

Comment: Please see my second edit which adds an example and explains what is the problem. The whole point is, without adjusting `i` and `j` correctly, we will train less batches when we apply the same formula to re-adjust `i` and `j`.